# Плавная анимация назад

Tags: css, html5, css3, svg, css-animation

```css
.container {
  padding: 2em 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 6em;
  margin: 3em auto;
  background: grey;
}
    
.item {
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  background: pink;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
    
.item:hover {
  animation: levitation 3s linear 0.1s infinite alternate;
}
    
@keyframes levitation {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-30%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">
    </div>
</div>
```

При hover на .item блок плавно левитирует, но при убирании hover-эффекта от блока, он резко падает. Что нужно дописать в css, чтобы при убирании hover-эффекта блок плавно опускался вниз?

Comment: Добавлено решение на SVG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант с JS и подпиской на события анимации:

```js
var matchesSelector = (function() {
  var fn = Element.prototype.matches ||
      Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector ||
      Element.prototype.mozMatchesSelector ||
      Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector;
  return function(element, selector) {
    return fn.call(element, selector);
  };
})();

function setAnimatedOnHover(element){  
  function onMouseOver(){
    element.classList.add('animated');
  }
  
  function onAnimationEnd(){
    if (matchesSelector(element, ':hover')) return;
    element.classList.remove('animated');
  }
  
  element.addEventListener('mouseover', onMouseOver, false);
  element.addEventListener('webkitAnimationIteration', onAnimationEnd, false);
  element.addEventListener('animationiteration', onAnimationEnd, false);
}

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.animated-on-hover'), setAnimatedOnHover);
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 2em 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 6em;
  margin: 3em auto;
  background: grey;
}

.item {
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  background: pink;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.item.animated {
  animation: levitation 1s linear 0.1s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes levitation {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-30%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item animated-on-hover"></div>
</div>
```

Альтернативный вариант на чистом CSS (довольно своеобразный, конечно):

```css
.container {
  padding: 2em 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 6em;
  margin: 3em auto;
  background: grey;
}

.item-zero {
  height: 0;
  transition: height 1s;
  animation: levitation 3s linear 0.1s infinite alternate;
}
    
.item-zero:hover {
  height: 4em;
}
    
.item {
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  background: pink;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
    
@keyframes levitation {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-30%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-zero">
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает! ))
не нужен ли стажер в помощь ? )

Comment: @SvArt713, рад, что помогло. Помощь с чем? :)

Comment: )) типо стажера на обучение ?

Comment: Возникает проблема, если таких блоков будет несколько, можно ли это как-то исправить ?
http://codepen.io/SvArt713/pen/QKeBOV

Comment: @SvArt713, просто уберите `.container:hover` с 23 строчки в стилях, он там не нужен — анимация запускается не на `:hover`, а скриптами, и убирается скриптами (иначе как раз при исчезании `:hover` всё прервётся). А насчёт стажёра — я сам пока, можно сказать, без работы, куда тут брать. :)

Comment: Не правильно обьяснил... Просто мне нужно чтобы при наведении на общий блок (в данном случае container) картинка начинала левитировать, а когда убирается с него (или смещаем курсор на соседний), то в этом блоке она опускалась, а в активном (на который навели) работала аналогично. 
понял )) просто я html/css вроде неплохо знаю, а вот JS хочу выучить, но во время изучения возникают вопросы, а спросить нету у кого...

Comment: @SvArt713, [вот так](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RoNPME)? Насчёт вопросов — можем, если хотите, обменяться контактами.

Comment: Да, то что нужно! Спасибо огромное! ))
@ArtyomVSvinin - телеграмм (здесь удобнее общаться)
https://vk.com/svinin713 - Вк
буду рад общению! ))

Comment: Добавите ? или дайте свои контакты )

Comment: @SurfinBird хочу спросить зачем нужно было добавлять в переменную matchesSelector анонимную функцию и что делает это функция?

Comment: @Избытоксусликов если сразу вернуть `fn` вместо обёртки в анонимную функцию, вызывать пришлось бы как `matchesSelector.call(element, selector)`, так как `fn` ожидает, что элемент будет передан как `this`.

Comment: @SurfinBird спасибо за объяснение.

Answer (score 1):

### SVG решение

**Наведите курсор мышки на квадратики в любом очередности**

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    
   width="300" height="300">
  <style>
  :hover#levit1,
  :hover#levit2,
  :hover#levit3
  {
   fill:dodgerblue;
  }
   </style>  
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="grey" /> 
 
 <rect id="levit1" x="25" y="150" width="50" height="50" fill="pink" >
  <animate attributeName="y" begin="mouseover"  dur="5s" restart="whenNotActive" values="150;50;150" />
 </rect>
   <rect id="levit2" x="125" y="150" width="50" height="50" fill="yellowgreen" >
        <animate attributeName="y" begin="mouseover"  dur="5s" restart="whenNotActive" values="150;50;150" />
   </rect>
  <rect id="levit3" x="225" y="150" width="50" height="50" fill="violet" >
     <animate attributeName="y" begin="mouseover"  dur="5s" restart="whenNotActive" values="150;50;150" />
  </rect>
 
 </svg>
```

Начало анимации `begin="mouseover"`

Чтобы квадратики не дергались при повторном наведении курсора, установлен запрет на повторный запуск анимации.

`restart="whenNotActive"`

Перемещение по оси "Y" во время анимации

`values="150;50;150"`